# Webpack plugin for pre-executing certain pieces of code

Tags: javascript, webpack, plugins, ramda.js, lenses

in our application we're using functional approach. For accessing schema properties e.g.

```
objectSchema: {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    prop1: {
      type: 'string'
      }
    }
  }
```

we're using lenses like `lensesFromSchema(objectSchema)` which results with lenses like `viewProp1(obj)`, `setProp1(obj)` etc.

problem with that approach is that `lensesFromSchema()` is taking about 40% of whole in-browser script evaluation time.

is there any way (webpack or anything else) to execute this function (`lensesFromSchema(objectSchema)`) at build time? all possible outputs from `lensesFromSchema` are predictable at build time.

Comment: I think you need to share 1) the implementation of `lenseFromSchema` and 2) the method you used to get those metrics. 40% may seems a lot but if you look at it holistically, it may be ok.

Comment: Also important to ask is whether the call to `lensesFromSchema` is taking all that time or if that time is being spent inside the functions it generates.  If it's the former, then there is likely something seriously wrong with that function.  If it's the latter, it may be entirely normal.  A quick test would be to capture the functions it generates and then run it manually with those functions instead.  If that leads to a major speed improvement, you need to look carefully at `lensesFromSchema`.  As to a Webpack plugin, I don't know, but there are always ways to write compilers for your code.